# How do I fix inaccessibility error in C#?`

Tags: c#

When I run my C# app, it shows the following error

> *Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'timesheet.libs.DbObject' is less accessible than method 'timesheet.model.usertimesheet.usertimesheet(timesheet.libs.DbObject)'   C:\Users\user\Desktop\Interface+code\Interface+code\timesheet\model\usertimesheet.cs*
>
> *Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'timesheet.libs.DbObject' is less accessible than method 'timesheet.MainFormMDI.setdbobject(timesheet.libs.DbObject)' C:\Users\user\Desktop\Interface+code\Interface+code\timesheet\MainFormMDI.cs*
>
> *Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'timesheet.libs.DbObject' is less accessible than method 'timesheet.model.user.user(timesheet.libs.DbObject)' C:\Users\user\Desktop\Interface+code\Interface+code\timesheet\model\user.cs*
>
> *Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'timesheet.libs.DbObject' is less accessible than method 'timesheet.model.project.project(timesheet.libs.DbObject)'   C:\Users\user\Desktop\Interface+code\Interface+code\timesheet\model\project.cs*

I have a snippet of login.cs  as

```
MainFormMDI mainform = new MainFormMDI();
mainform.setdbobject(dbobject);
mainform.setuserobject(userobj);
mainform.Show();
```

`MainFormMDI.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using timesheet.model;
using timesheet.libs;

namespace timesheet
{
    public partial class MainFormMDI : Form
    {
        private DbObject dbobject;
        private  user userobj;

        public MainFormMDI( )
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void setdbobject(DbObject dbobject) 
        {
            this.dbobject = dbobject;
        }

        public void setuserobject(user userobj) 
        {
            this.userobj = userobj;
        }

        private void MainFormMDI_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void adminPanelToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I tried other solutions like changing the dbobject and user class to public but nothing changes. I want to pass the userobject and the dbobject to the MainFormMDI  class to be able to carry out further actions on these objects. I will be happy to hear your fixes .

Comment: It should have worked.  Where is the `dbobject` that you're passing coming from, and what is its accessibility?

Comment: I think you're going to need to show us the relevant code in `timesheet.libs`.

Comment: Did my answer fix your problem or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make timesheet.libs.DbObject public. You then need to recompile the library (making an assumption that libs indicates it's in a library) and then rebuild the project that uses it.

The problem is that DbObject is either private or internal and it's being passed as a parameter to a public method. If the method is public, then all it parameter types must be as well.

Comment: That sure is what it sounds like.